# Bundled Data Directory is not recognized in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tesseract, python-tesseract

i'm making a basic OCR with pytesseract, I have this line in my Code

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'data/A/tesseract/tesseract.exe'
```

and run pyinstaller with

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "data;data" OCR.py
```

but when I launch the application I get this error

```
data/A/tesseract/tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

But if I omit the `-F`

```
pyinstaller --add-data "data;data" OCR.py
```

it just works fine with no errors, But I need it to be a `--one-file` , How can I Fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Issue Resolved by adding

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

at the beginning of the script